# Unable to run ElasticSearch tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a unit test which would test creating an ES Node. As per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html,
I have a test class which extends ESIntegTestCase. However, when I run it, I get an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase
```

I have been investigating if there are any dependency collisions, but there aren't any. In my pom, I have the following -

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
     <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a jar hell problem.

Comment: Can you post the steps you did? I am having the same problem but don't know where to start to fix. What I can say is the the Elasticsearch Test Framework is about the hardest thing I have ever dealt with. The documentation is severely lacking and it is too difficult to setup properly.